# How to write Queue<T> content to file while Queue is being added to in another class

Tags: java, android, linked-list, queue, fileoutputstream

I have a Listener class which adds values to a Queue, I have another class that contains the Queue and writes it to a file. Both of these classes are running in background thread.

**Listener class**

```
private AccelerometerQueue mLogQueue; //Queue class implements Runnable
private Thread mQueueThread; //Thread to run Runnable of Queue class
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    synchronized (this) {
        mLogQueue.addToQueue(
                new AccelerometerVector(
                        System.currentTimeMillis(),
                        sensorEvent.timestamp,
                        sensorEvent.values[0],
                        sensorEvent.values[1],
                        sensorEvent.values[2]
                )
        );


        mQueueThread = new Thread(mLogQueue);
        mQueueThread.start();
    }
}
```

**Queue class** imlpements Runnable and has this LinkedList

```
public void addToQueue(AccelerometerVector vector) {
    mQueue.add(vector);
}

public synchronized int getQueueSize(){
    return mQueue.size();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        mLogFile = createLogFile();
        mLogOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mLogFile, true);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (!mQueue.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            mLogOutStream.write(mQueue.poll().getDataStringLine().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (mLogFile.length() > AppConstants.LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE) {
            try {
                reportCurrentLogFileIsFinished(mLogFile);
                mLogOutStream.flush();
                mLogOutStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mLogOutStream = new FileOutputStream(createLogFile(), true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private File createLogFile() {

    String datePart = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date());
    String namePart = "log_" + datePart + ".csv";
    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + File.separator + AppConstants.APP_LOG_FOLDER_NAME);

    folder.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(folder + File.separator + namePart);

    if (!file.exists()) { //create the file if not exist
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Can not create file: " + file.getName());
        }
    }
    if (file.exists()) {
        return file;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My goal is to save the queue content to storage and the size of the files should not exceed 256Kb, and when a file reaches 256kb a new file should be created.

What the code currently does is writes few files with sizes like 2 or 3 Kb and then it throws the exception in the `createLogFile()` method complaining the file can not be created (I see this in the Logcat).

The question is, what am I doing wrong and what might be the possible solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured out the problem.

The first problem was that I started the `mQueueThread` inside the `onSensorChanged` method. This caused a new thread started on receiving update from the `onSensorChanged` method and cause meamory leak or some other serious problems. So I moved it to the constructor.

Secondly I changed the Queue type to `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` but I dont have any explanation...might be another type would do better.

Lastly, I changed the implementation of `Runnable` to the following:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (mLogOutStream != null && !mQueue.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                mLogOutStream.write(mQueue.poll().getDataStringLine().getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (mLogFile.length() > AppConstants.LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    reportCurrentLogFileIsFinished(mLogFile);
                    try {
                        if (mLogOutStream != null) {
                            mLogOutStream.flush();
                            mLogOutStream.close();
                            mLogOutStream = null;
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        mLogFile = createLogFile();
                        mLogOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mLogFile, true);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These changes took care of the problems. Hope this can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume you are using a synchronized collection:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

Attempting to reopen the file may be the issue.  Given that there is a single thread writing to the file I would suggest that you open the file and keep it open.

Finally, what exception are you getting?

Comment: There is no opening file operation at this point of my code and work. and I am using LinkedList rather than synchronizedlist

Comment: this opens the file:try {
                mLogOutStream = new FileOutputStream(createLogFile(), true);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: Not Synchronizing the list will likely get you in trouble when the list is being modified by multiple threads.

Comment: I get the IOException on creating the new file...I still cant figure this out!

Comment: I also get java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

Comment: Do you have more that one thread attempting to write to the file?  Have you verified that you have appropriate permissions to write to the file?  One thing to try is to change the code to not use the background threads.  Then you can verify that the code and environment are correct (if it all works) and then focus on the threading issues which can be more difficult to resolve.

Comment: Well I am pretty sure there is only one thread writing to file. and file is being created and written to but after a short while expections rise and it screws up